# PayPal IPN $_POST['txn_id'] not set

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm using the PayPal sandbox to do a subscribe button and then when I get the IPN response for a subscription or a subscription cancelation $_POST['txn_id'] is never set.

So I don't know how to identify transactions to only accept unique ones

Thanks!

EDIT: for example all the info that I have in POST for a subscr_cancel are : amount1, amount3 , address_status, subscr_date,  payer_id, address_street, mc_amount1, mc_amount3, charset, address_zip, first_name, reattempt, address_country_code, address_name, otify_version
subscr_id
custom
payer_status
business
address_country
address_city
verify_sign
payer_email
btn_id
last_name
address_state
receiver_email
recurring
txn_type
item_name
mc_currency
residence_country
test_ipn
period1
period3
correlation_id

Comment: Can you confirm that you are indeed receiving an IPN to your IPN URL? For instance, are any other PayPal `$_POST` variables set?

Comment: Yes I got all other data in POST, even the txn_type so that's weird that I don't have the txn_id

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That helps a lot. My explanation below should clear up your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Table 2. Summary of subscription variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB0901HT):

> For subscription variables, the transaction ID (txn_id) is only available for USD Payment and
>   Multi-Currency Payment transaction types (txn_type).

As expected, PayPal will not send the `txn_id` to your IPN for the transaction type, `subscr_cancel`, and will **only send `txn_id` if the transaction type is `subscr_payment`**.

For further explanation on which variables are sent to your IPN URL based on your transaction, please check out [IPN and PDT Variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB0901HT).

Comment: Thanks! Ok so no way to identify a transaction of type subscr_cancel to make sure that is unique?

Comment: If you have your own method of uniquely identifying transactions, or you have the transaction ID from the payment transaction, you may send your own variables to PayPal, which will return to your IPN. -- You can use either `invoice` or `custom`, and you will see these in your IPN.

Comment: A cancellation is not a transaction; no transaction takes place, hence no txn_id is available. You can identify the subscription / recurring payment by the subscription ID in `subscr_id`.

Comment: Good point about `subscr_id`. Although, it would be easy to confuse a cancellation as a *transaction*, since it is classified as a *transaction* type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `$_REQUEST['txn_id']` as this may be sent to your server via `GET`.

Comment: Yes i just tested it right now $_GET['txn_id'] and $_REQUEST['txn_id'] and they are not set